# JSF convertDateTime validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, methods

I have a problem mentioned in the topic. I have

```
    <h:selectOneMenu class="time" id="time" value="#{auctionBean.expDate}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="11/11/1111 11:11:11" itemLabel="1 day" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{auctionBean.calculateExpDate(4)}" itemLabel="4 days" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{auctionBean.calculateExpDate(7)}" itemLabel="7 days" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{auctionBean.calculateExpDate(14)}" itemLabel="14 days" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is i am getting Validation Error: Value is not valid message for all items but first one.
The method:

```
public String calculateExpDate(int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("data: " + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
    return formatter.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

It returns String in good format. Output from system.out:

```
INFO:   data: 10/10/2013 20:40:04
```

Where is the problem? I have no clue at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good one!

If what you are getting is a VALIDATION error, not a CONVERSION problem, then the probable scenario is:

- the list of available values is created, and the values have precision of 1 second,
- user picks one of them,
- **but** on postback the available values get recalculated, and they are all a **couple of seconds later than the original ones**.
- so the value that your user picked is **no more available** on the list of possible values,
- and so a validation error happens (which is what JSF does always when the value chosen is no longer on the list of select items).
- you do not get it with the first item, because **it's the only one that does not change with time** :-).

If you move the backing bean to view scope (or session scope), or cut the precision, it should work. Or better yet - make an enum with values of NOW, IN_2_DAYS, IN_4_DAYS and so on. And calculate the real date after the enum is chosen.

Comment: I'd go ahead with the enum and calculate only after selection.

Answer (score 1):

fdreger is right! I marked his post as an answer. Thanks:)
This is my solution if you are lazy (however it might be done better I guess):

JSF:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="time" id="time" value="#{auctionBean.choosenOption}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{auctionBean.days}" var="days" itemValue="#{days}" itemLabel="#{days.label}"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

fragment of my auctionBean:

```
public enum Days {

    IN_1_DAY("1 dzień", 1),
    IN_4_DAYS("4 dni", 4),
    IN_7_DAYS("7 dni", 7),
    IN_14_DAYS("14 dni", 14);
    private String label;
    private int days;
    private Days(String label, int days) {
        this.label = label;
        this.days = days;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public Date calculateExpDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, this.days);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
private Days choosenOption;

public void setChoosenOption(Days choosenOption) {
    this.choosenOption = choosenOption;
    expDate = choosenOption.calculateExpDate();
}

public Days getChoosenOption() {
    return choosenOption;
}

public Days[] getDays() {
    return Days.values();
}
```

User chooses how many days his auction should be active and i calculate what is an expiration date.
expDate is Date object which i set only once, after choosing the single enum and sumbitting the form. Pretty good solution suggested :)

Comment: You can improve it more by putting `calculateExpDate` logic in the enum itself. Then you just have to do `expDate = chosenOption.calculateExpDate()`.

Comment: you are right as always BalusC:) I've edited the post